# Check if the given element is the last of an list or not

Tags: list, prolog

I have this predicate and this works.

```
last(X,[Y|X]).
last(X,[Y|Z]) :- last(X,Z).
```

But I also want to do it with my list_merge predicate.

```
list_merge([], X, X).
list_merge([X | L1], L2, [X | L3]) :-
   list_merge(L1, L2, L3).
```

How can I combine them?

Answer (score 0):

`X` is the last part of `Y` if there is something you can merge with `X` to get `Y`
:

```
last(X,Y) :- list_merge( _, X, Y ).
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that [last is already defined](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=last/2) in swi-prolog, and [here is its code](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/lists.pl?show=src#last/2).

Here is a corrected version of your `last`:

```
last_play(Last, [_|[Last]]).
last_play(Last, [_|T]) :-
    last_play(Last, T).
```

Results:

```
?- last_play(E, L).
L = [_, E] ;
L = [_, _, E] ;
L = [_, _, _, E] ;
L = [_, _, _, _, E] ;
L = [_, _, _, _, _, E]
```

There's 2 problems with it:

1. It fails for a list containing a single element:

```
?- last_play(E, [1]).
false.
```

2. It leaves an unwanted choicepoint:

```
?- last_play(E, [1,2,3]).
E = 3 ;
false.
```

The linked code above has neither of these problems, because it uses first-argument indexing on `[]` vs `[Head|Tail]`.

```
?- last([1], E).
E = 1.

?- last([1,2,3], E).
E = 3.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is definitely not working according to the expected behavior of "last". This is what I see:

```
?- last(Last, [a,b,c,d]).
Last = [b, c, d] ;
Last = [c, d] ;
Last = [d] ;
Last = [] ;
false.
```

Is this really what you intended?

The solution in the other answer just repeats the same answers.

Here is how you could have defined "last" (... element of a list)

```
last(X, [X])
last(X, [_|Y]) :- last(X, Y).
```

This works (try it!) even if it isn't optimal.

To get the last element of a list using "append" in the other direction, you should type:

```
?- append(_Front, [Last], List).
```

You can do exactly the same with your "list_merge". However "merge" also has a *different* expected behavior. You'd expect:

```
?- merge([b,m,x], [a,n,y], Merged).
Merged = [a,b,m,n,x,y].
```